# Remove posts from Review if a mod has already commented

Tags: feature-request, moderators, flagging, review-page

I'm sure I'm not the only one who thinks "Oh, a flaggable post! Aw, mod already got it."

I believe it would save time and enthusiasm to remove such mod-commented posts from the Review page.